# Snapchat receives blank chats

Tags: snapchat

Since signing up for Snapchat about a month ago, I have regularly received Snapchats that are simply black screens (and obviously confirmed that the sender did not send a blank screen) about 1 out of every 4 messages.

I have the LG Spectrum 2, running Android 4.1.2 (JB) and just did a factory reset in an unsuccessful attempt to fix Snapchat. I have tried using an old version of Snapchat (v2.something) which received less blanks, but still some, as well as the new Beta version which received just as many as the most recent version. I even tried signing up for a new account and deleting the old one - this worked for about two days and then the same problem started again with the new account.